# Required permissions not showing in discord.py error handling

Tags: discord.py

I want that when user dont have perms to use command, it will also tell what perms is needed. Here is code:

````
if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingPermissions):
        noperms = discord.Embed(title="<a:wrong:1199385940263706765> ERROR",
                      description=f"```\nNO PERMISSIONS TO USE THIS COMMAND\n```\n**REQUIRED PERMISSIONS:**\n```\n{missing_permissions}\n```",
                      colour=0xf50000)
        await ctx.send(embed=noperms)
````

Also what is error tag, if bot dont have perms to do something???

Tried to use {missing_permissions} but its not working

Comment: can we see the full context of what this if statement is in? see [mre]